# How to denote a row or a column of the Jacobian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, notation, jacobian

The Jacobian matrix of a vector valued function $f$ can be denoted $$J(f(x))$$

where each element of this matrix is given as $$J_{ij}(f(x))$$

Does anyone know good way of denoting the row or the column of the Jacobian matrix? For example, is it common to denote the $i$th row as $[J(f(x))]_i$?

Comment: yeah that should be fine

Comment: Moreover, the row $i$ is $\nabla f_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $(i,k)$ entry of the Jacobian at $x$ is
$${\partial f_i\over\partial x_k}(x)\ .\tag{1}$$
The $i^{\rm th}$ row of the Jacobian is then given by
$$\left({\partial f_i\over\partial x_1},{\partial f_i\over\partial x_2},\ldots,{\partial f_i\over\partial x_n}\right)_x=\nabla f_i(x)\ .$$
The $k^{\rm th}$ column of the Jacobian contains the partial derivatives of the $m$ components $f_i$ of $f$ with respect to the $k^{\rm th}$ variable. There is no standard notation for such a column. In any case $$J_f(x)\,e_k$$ or $${\partial f\over\partial x_k}$$
are correct, albeit typographically somewhat clumsy. I usually write $f_{i.k}(x)$ for the partial derivative $(1)$ and $f_{.k}(x)$ for said column vector, omitting the $(x)$ when appropriate.